# Android Studio batch import drawables?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, I have an exisiting project. I've recived some images that are in their respective drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi etc... folders. Is there a way I can bring all these in Android Studio at once? Rather than drag/drop each image and each of it's different resoluutions into the IDE?

Comment: Probably your best bet is to bring them over in the filesystem instead of through the IDE UI. If it's something you need to do very often a little shell scripting could help you out.

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28363332/3758898

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast ways to import drawables in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503229/fast-ways-to-import-drawables-in-android-studio)