# How to import multiple image assets to android studio at once?

Tags: android

This question has already been asked by different ways by another users but their question doesn't properly address my issue.

I am making a playing card game in android, so I need to be able to import all the 52 card image to android. However, so far, I couldn't see an option to do this in android studio. After that I had installed [Android Drawable Importer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658?pr=) on a suggestion in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503229/fast-ways-to-import-drawables-in-android-studio).

These posts doesn't really address my issue. My primary aim is not to scale images for different sizes (however it is also one of my aims), but to import multiple image resources at once.

I have already tried dragging and dropping image files, but not to avail. I have android studio version of 1.4 and I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks.

Comment: It's just ... https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-birthday-card-app-image#1

Answer (score -2):

Just drag and drop the image files to an drawable folder!
You don't need to use an importer

Comment: He clearly stated that 'drag-and-drop' didn't work. It doesn't work for me too. Also if you've got the link to the duplicate version of the question please drop it here. Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-birthday-card-app-image#1 is easy nowawayds