# Android Studio Image Importer

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating this question just to try to organize this topic which I 've seen is very requested but not many good answers.

So I've been wondering the best way to import an image (icon, android drawable or custom image). And by best way, I mean, maintain the quality of image as well optimize time-effort.

The tools I've encountered so far are:

**[Android Drawable Importer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer)**
Which I've tested and it is pretty good. But, it is not very compatible nowadays with Android Studio, and it is not updated anymore anyway. (Sometimes I get exceptions while trying to import).
[Ref. Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28503506/3291164)

**[Romannurik](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html)**
Seems good to generate general Android icons, but, it is online and doesnt have a plugin. Haven't tested for custom images and don't know if it is possible.

[**Android Studio Icon Asset**](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html)
Seems really good to import android icons, but sometimes it generates gray images (more about in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28704026/3291164))

**[Android Studio Vector Asset](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#running)**
Well, the process is almost the same as the icon asset, but only accept vector images, also, it implicates in some code changes, not very good for middle project. (But haven't tested it, just assuming)

few others: [Python Android Asset Resizer](https://github.com/twaddington/android-asset-resizer), [Photoshop Script](https://github.com/xcesco/ic_launcher_exporter), [Let Android downsample them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19196749/3291164)

Comment: was this a bad question? would like to get some answers on it :(