# Is there a built-in method to add drawable that is not an icon using Android Studio?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, drawable, android-drawable

I know that I can right-click on res folder, select "New > Image asset" but while it allows me to select type of added icon it assumes that I want to add an icon.

I know that I can manually generate images and move them into drawble-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi but I assume that it is possible to automate it and supply single image that will be scaled to create lower-resolution versions.

I know about [Fast ways to import drawables in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503229/fast-ways-to-import-drawables-in-android-studio) but it was not restricted to built-in options and an accepted version is [plugin that received last update in 2016](https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin) and appears to be [no longer maintained - NullPointerException report received no response from maintainer](https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin/issues/152).

Comment: What's the question exactly? it's not clear

Comment: @y.allam I want to provide single image that Android Studio will scale to create drawble-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, rather than manually creating scaled images and copying them into folders. How can I improve second paragraph to clarify this?

Comment: i don't know about a good up-to-date tool for Android Studio, but here's a solution that i think is pretty good and needs not much effort to generate scaled drawables https://stackoverflow.com/a/25355105/2553984

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny have you used drawable-anydpi?

Comment: This didn't work for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31275345/2549850

Comment: @KashanDanish No, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Are your drawables svg (vector) images?

Comment: @MinasMina No, AFAIK there is no point in creating separate SVG for different scales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately after posting and creating a bounty, I found that it was already asked as [Is there a way to create xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi drawables from a large scale image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196616/is-there-a-way-to-create-xxhdpi-xhdpi-hdpi-mdpi-and-ldpi-drawables-from-a-lar)

Therefore [Is there a way to create xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi drawables from a large scale image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196616/is-there-a-way-to-create-xxhdpi-xhdpi-hdpi-mdpi-and-ldpi-drawables-from-a-lar/19196749#19196749) has some useful options quoted below:

Option #1: Just ship the `-xxhdpi` drawables and let Android downsample them for you at runtime (downside: will only work on fairly recent devices, where `-xxhdpi` is known).

Option #2: Automate the process within a graphics editor, per ssantos' answer.

Option #3: Script yourself a solution, using something like ImageMagick

(answers by CommonsWare)

I followed option #3