# Android: Same Image needs to be added in all drawable folders?

Tags: android, imageview, drawable, android-drawable

I am directly adding images in `drawable` folders and it is coming fine with `ImageView` tag `android:src="@drawable/image_name"` but I wonder what to do with the other `drawable` folders as shown below.

[image]

Do I need to add same image in all `drawable` folders or my way of adding images in `drawable` folders is wrong?

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is same, but the size should be different for each folders.
If you add the image only in drawable folder, same image will be loaded for all screen resolutions. So for eg: if the image size is small, this may result in bad image quality.

You can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669228/how-to-import-or-copy-images-to-the-res-folder-in-android-studio)

I use Android studio plugin [Android Drawable Importer](https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin)

Comment: so it means we have to add images in all drawable folders with different sizes

Comment: Well.. Theoretically Yes... But practically you can skip ldpi as very few devices now have this resolution and I usually skip HDPI as the android device can down/up scale from its closest resolution. And if the image size is really big (for eg background images), I also skip the xxxdpi...

Answer (score 1):

All these drawable folders represent different android phone densities. The best folder to put your images is drawable-xxhdpi as android automatically downscale or upscale the images depending on your devices density and most phones these days are on xxhdpi density.

If you put a image in drawable folder only there are chances that image may get distorted(as it upscales) in xxxhdpi density.

If you are putting images in xxhdpi ,make sure you create your images acc. to xxhdpi resolution.

If you don't feel the image is looking right in some phones than check the density of that phone and put an image in that specific density folder acc. to it's size(reduced or increased).

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in the drawable folder, no need to put it in other drawable-... folders because those folders and contents inside are created automatically by android studio.

Comment: my other drawable folders are empty. Images not automatically created in other folders when I add images in drawable folder.

Comment: The folders are automatically created. The image is not automatically up/down scaled

Comment: my drawable-... folders are just containing launcher logo.